# How to set global style of controls in Manipulate?

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate, output-formatting, fonts

I created a Manipulate code which is using several sliders, with the same font output (style, size, font familly, ...).  How can I save some space by defining a global style for all the slider controls ?

Here's a simple MWE to show what I mean :

```
Manipulate[
    ParametricPlot[
        {a Sin[b t + c], d Cos[f t + g]}, {t, 0, 6 Pi},
        Frame -> True, 
        PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}
    ],
    {{a, 1, Style[a, 12, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]}, 0, 5, 0.01},
    {{b, 1, Style[b, 12, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]}, 0, 10, 0.01},
    {{c, 1, Style[c, 12, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]}, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01},
    {{d, 1, Style[d, 12, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]}, 0, 5, 0.01},
    {{f, 1, Style[f, 12, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]}, 0, 10, 0.01},
    {{g, 1, Style[g, 12, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]}, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}
]
```

How can we declare the **style** once for all the controls ?  I know it's possible, but I'm unable to find the proper command for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the option `LabelStyle`:

```
labelstyle = Directive[12, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"];

Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{a Sin[b t + c], d Cos[f t + g]}, {t, 0, 6 Pi}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], 
  {{a, 1}, 0, 5,   0.01}, {{b, 1}, 0, 10,  0.01}, 
  {{c, 1}, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}, {{d, 1}, 0, 5, 0.01}, 
  {{f, 1}, 0, 10, 0.01}, {{g, 1}, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}, LabelStyle -> labelstyle]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can override `LabelStyle` settings by specifying styles for individual 
controls:

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{a Sin[b t + c],  Cos[ t ]}, {t, 0, 6 Pi}, 
  Frame -> True,  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], 
  {{a, 1, Style["abCDeFGh", FontFamily -> "Lucida Handwriting", Red, Bold,  20]},
    0, 5, 0.01}, 
  {{b, 1}, 0, 10, 0.01}, {{c, 1}, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01},  LabelStyle -> labelstyle]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Doh !  Thanks !  I knew it was so simple !

Answer (score 1):

I just found another way :

```
textStyle = Sequence[12, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"];

Manipulate[
    ParametricPlot[
        {a Sin[b t + c], d Cos[f t + g]}, {t, 0, 6 Pi},
        Frame -> True, 
        PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}
    ],
    {{a, 1, Style[a, textStyle]}, 0, 5, 0.01},
    {{b, 1, Style[b, textStyle]}, 0, 10, 0.01},
    {{c, 1, Style[c, textStyle]}, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01},
    {{d, 1, Style[d, textStyle]}, 0, 5, 0.01},
    {{f, 1, Style[f, textStyle]}, 0, 10, 0.01},
    {{g, 1, Style[g, textStyle]}, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}
]
```

Since I'm also using some buttons with another font style (Helvetica instead of Times), this solution appears to be better for my needs.